# exporting specific chars in html

Tags: html, powershell

I want to export a hash table of data to html via powershell, but the ConvertTo-HTML command does not seem to export certain characters.

For example:

If I had a table with a string containing the character "<", that table would then export a line like this:

```
<tr><td>&lt;</td></tr>
```

Is there any way, using my current approach, that I can export these characters without having to edit my HTML document afterwards?

Edit:

I am trying to use ConvertTo-HTML to create an HTML page with info pulled from a SQL server. I was able to do this, but the roadblock is trying to replace one of the table columns with images that correspond to the image path which is currently in the column. I need to edit those images so that they actually show up on the website, and inserting the actual html code for that was the way I considered doing it.

I looked into a different method editing the HTML document after it is exported, which worked for the most part, but I ended up getting an HTML document without the `<html>`, `<body>`, or even `<table>`.

The first line of the exported code:

```
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Redacted</td><td>AR</td><td>email</td><td>+41 61 681 85 25</td><td><img src= "filepath to image folder" alt = "Cannot Find Image" height="100"></td></tr>
```

The method I attempted to use second can be found here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8a3c8dc5-169c-4b61-9bc3-672a7d1e31b3/powershell-to-open-and-edit-html-file?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: &lt; is the way that you need to represent `<` in HTML, because an unmodified `<` will be interpreted as the start of a tag.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to instead export a  `<` instead of the standard &lt;. I know that it won't show up on the website, but will instead edit the html code.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to use ConvertTo-HTML to create an HTML page with info pulled from a SQL server. I was able to do this, but the roadblock is trying to replace one of the table columns with images that correspond to the image path which is currently in the column. I need to edit those images so that they actually show up on the website, and inserting the actual html code for that was the way I considered doing it.

Comment: Edit that into the question, please, and include any research you've done to try to solve the problem on your own, so that anyone attempting to assist you doesn't redo any work that you've found useless.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert-ToHTML` returns a string, which can then be further processed before writing it out to a file. If your table would contain the row

```
<tr><td><IMG SRC="foo.png"></td></tr>
```

it will be converted to HTML as

```
<tr><td>&lt;IMG SRC=&quot;foo.png&quot;&gt;</td></tr>
```

as you discovered.

Since it's a string, though, it can then be further processed before writing it out to the file. If the latter (converted) string is stored in the variable `$imagelink`, you can then use the PowerShell `-replace` operator:

```
$imagelink = $imagelink -replace "&lt;","<"
```

and so on, replacing each HTML character entity with its corresponding actual character. When all replacements have been made, you simply write it out to a file with `Set-Content`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet outputs text, so if you know what your image paths are that you want to keep you can search the text for those and convert them back after `ConvertTo-Html` encodes them to HTML. Consider this pseudo-code:

```
$HTML = $SQLdata | ConvertTo-Html -As Table
ForEach($ImageLink in $SQLdata.imagelinks){
    $EncodedLink = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($ImageLink)
    $HTML = $HTML -replace $EncodedLink, $ImageLink
}
```

So first I generate the HTML from the SQL data. Then I loop through the column with the images (which I referred to as `$SQLdata.imagelinks`), and for each string I encode it to HTML (just like the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet did), so that I know what I'm looking for. Then I simply replace any instances of the encoded string with the original from the SQL data. Rinse and repeat until all the image links are replaced back to their original text.

For an example that you can sink your teeth into, using your string of `<img src= "filepath to image folder" alt = "Cannot Find Image" height="100">`, after HTML encoding that would become:

```
&lt;img src= &quot;filepath to image folder&quot; alt = &quot;Cannot Find Image&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;&gt;
```

So in your first line of your table you would actually see:

```
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Redacted</td><td>AR</td><td>email</td><td>+41 61 681 85 25</td><td>&lt;img src= &quot;filepath to image folder&quot; alt = &quot;Cannot Find Image&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;&gt;</td></tr>
```

So we can run a few simple lines to demonstrate that this works:

```
$OriginalLink = '<img src= "filepath to image folder" alt = "Cannot Find Image" height="100">'
$EncodedLink = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($OriginalLink)
$BrokenHtml = '<tr><td>Name</td><td>Redacted</td><td>AR</td><td>email</td><td>+41 61 681 85 25</td><td>&lt;img src= &quot;filepath to image folder&quot; alt = &quot;Cannot Find Image&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;&gt;</td></tr>'
$BrokenHtml -replace $EncodedLink, $OriginalLink
```

Now technically `-replace` uses RegEx (Regular Expression) matching, so if you run into trouble trying to match things, or get invalid pattern errors you can escape the encoded link to be regex friendly, but I'm pretty sure that the process of HTML encoding it should make it relatively regex safe. If you have trouble use:

```
$HTML = $SQLdata | ConvertTo-Html -As Table
ForEach($ImageLink in $SQLdata.imagelinks){
    $EncodedLink = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($ImageLink)
    $RegexLink = [regex]::Escape($EncodedLink)
    $HTML = $HTML -replace $RegexLink, $ImageLink
}
```

**Edit:** I will also explain HTML, and the use of HTML special characters. So, the reason that you pipe `<` into `ConvertTo-Html`, and receive `&lt;` is that the less than symbol is a special character. It is reserved for things such as defining HTML tags. There are many characters that have codes like that, which most any modern browser will convert to the associated character before rendering the content to the user. You can check out a list here: http://www.html.am/reference/html-special-characters.cfm.

The reason for this is that `ConvertTo-Html` is trying to prevent you from breaking the HTML that it outputs. Sure, your `<img src...>` line is valid HTML, and you know that, but the cmdlet doesn't. Say you had a string that said `Java < PowerShell`, that's not valid HTML, so to be safe the cmdlet simply looks for any reserved characters and converts them to their entity name, so that you end up with text that is safe to render and will not corrupt the HTML structure of the document.

Comment: You still haven't explained why &lt isn't the right thing to put in your html stream.  Any good browser will render that as the less than character before putting it on the screen.

Comment: @WalterMitty I have updated my answer to include information about HTML special characters, and why his `<` is converted to `&lt;`.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I put my comment in the wrong place.  I meant to ask the OP why &lt was a problem.  Your answer is just fine.

Comment: @WalterMitty Oh, I can explain that. The OP has valid HTML in one column that will render an image. When it is passed through `ConvertTo-Html` it gets web encoded, and is then displayed as text instead of actually inserting the image into the table's cell. So instead of a picture the user sees `<img src= "filepath to image folder" alt = "Cannot Find Image" height="100">`